# Save date 'without' time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

At the moment I save my date like this: `ISODate("2014-11-17T16:19:16.224Z")`, but I want this result: `ISODate("2014-11-16T23:00:00Z")`. How can I do this?

Comment: Set the parts you don't want saved to 0. In your example, you would set the minutes and seconds to 0.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the parts you don't want saved to 0. In your example, you would set the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to 0.

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0);
date.setMilliseconds(0);

var isoDateString = date.toISOString();

console.log(isoDateString);
```

Answer (score 6):

An easier alternative is to use [`Date.setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) - in single call you can set what you need - from hours to milliseconds. If you just want to get rid of the time.

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log ( date );
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, a less verbose option:

```js
var date = new Date();

var isoDateString = date.toISOString().substring(0,10);

console.log(isoDateString);
```

Answer (score 1):

To Save a date without a time stamp:

```
let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US');
console.log(date)
// OUTPUT -> m/d/yyyy
```

Use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to find options to add as paramaters for the `toLocaleDateString` function